# swift NSPredicate logical OR

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I've got a single string substitution working with NSPredicate but returning core data records that contain either StringA or StringB doesn't seem to be something I can figure out. I want something like this:

```
let filter = NSPredicate(format: ("%K = %@", "type", "StringA") OR ("%K = %@", "type", "StringB"))
```

But of course that doesn't work. Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify a *format string*,
followed by a comma-separated list of *arguments* to substitute into the format:

```
let filter = NSPredicate(format:"%K = %@ OR %K = %@", "type", "StringA", "type", "StringB")
```

If the keys are not reserved words and do not contain special characters then you 
can specify them directly in the format string:

```
let filter = NSPredicate(format:"type = %@ OR type = %@", "StringA", "StringB")
```